# Python dataframe how to group by one column and get sum of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new data frame which has 2 columns, grouped by `Striker_Id` and other column which has sum of 'Batsman_Scored' corresponding to the grouped 'Striker_Id'

Eg:

```
Striker_ID  Batsman_Scored
1            0
2            8 
...
```

[image]

I tried this `ball.groupby(['Striker_Id'])['Batsman_Scored'].sum()` but this is what I get:

```
Striker_Id
1      0000040141000010111000001000020000004001010001...
2      0000000446404106064011111011100012106110621402...
3      0000121111114060001000101001011010010001041011...
4      0114110102100100011010000000006010011001111101...
5      0140016010010040000101111100101000111410011000...
6      1100100000104141011141001004001211200001110111...
```

It doesn't sum, only joins all the numbers. What's the alternative?

Comment: They're _strings_, not integers.

Comment: Why is it converting to string, all my columns are `int`

Comment: You likely have non-numeric data in your column, meaning that nothing short of `pd.to_numeric` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your columns were loaded as strings. While loading them from a CSV, try applying a converter -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'Batsman_Scored' : int})
```

Or,

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'Batsman_Scored' : pd.to_numeric})
```

If that doesn't work, then convert to integer after loading -

```
df['Batsman_Scored'] = df['Batsman_Scored'].astype(int)
```

Or,

```
df['Batsman_Scored'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Batsman_Scored'], errors='coerce')
```

Now, performing the groupby should work -

```
r = df.groupby('Striker_Id')['Batsman_Scored'].sum()
```

---

Without access to your data, I can only speculate. But it seems like, at some point, your data contains non-numeric data that prevents pandas from being able to perform conversions, resulting in those columns being retained as strings. It's a little difficult to pinpoint this problematic data until you actually load it in and do something like

```
df.col.str.isdigit().any()
```

That'll tell you if there are any non-numeric items. Note that it only works for integers, float columns cannot be debugged like this.

Also, another way of seeing what columns have corrupt data would be to query `dtypes` -

```
df.dtypes
```

Which will give you a listing of all columns and their datatypes. Use this to figure out what columns need parsing -

```
for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == object]:
    print(c)
```

You can then apply the methods outlined above to fix them.

Comment: this worked, but why did it happen? Also, how do I know my other numeric fields aren't messed up same way?

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri See my edit? I can only speculate without your data.